# In Urbancode Deploy, what is the impact of changing the External Agent URL, from IP to hostname?

Tags: urbancode

I have a UCD server, where the External Agent URL is an IP address 9.x. One of the users has requested to change that IP to a hostname, reason being that his agent can't reach that IP because that segment (9.x) is blocked, but they can reach it using the hostname because the agent can use a different route.
What will be the impact to the agents connected to that server if I change the External Agent URL ?  Will they need to be updated too ?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to update before this question. After a discussion with a developer, I found out there is no impact in changing the IP address for the URL. This is transparent for the agents, and they don't need to be updated in any form.

I wanted to provide this update in case someone find it useful in the future.

Regards